# Saving CalenderExtender Selected date in Sql Server Database 2008

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am using an ajax calendar extender I want to save the records to a gridview on the selected date but i am getting default date like '1900-01-01'.

How to save the date as i am selecting the date in Calender Extender. Please help me.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: how u r retrieving the date? Place the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably not format the date as SQL wait for. Use this format to enter it to your database.

This is the code on the page.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtYouDateTime" runat="server" Width="190px" ></asp:TextBox> 

<asp:ImageButton runat="Server" ID="ImgCal1" ImageUrl="calendar.png" AlternateText="Click to show calendar" OnClientClick="return false;"  />

<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
                    TargetControlID="txtYouDateTime" PopupButtonID="ImgCal1" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm" />
```

Then on code behind, that convert the date time from user input to sql input. You need to make some more check like if there is text, if datetime parse it or not, etc...

```
DateTime.Parse(txtYouDateTime.Text).ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: But i want to store the date by using Insert query.

Comment: @Naresh in the insert, use this type of format. I can not type here all the insert command from the moment you do not have type any of your code.

Comment: I am writing the code like this, txtDOB.text=calenderExtender1.selectedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
But it was save as like '1900-01-01 12:00:00 00'

Comment: @Naresh I have make an update with the code on page and on code behind.

Comment: Thanks for giving the code, I h've tried but the error is
     String was not recognized as a valid datetime

Comment: When i am recreated the textbox and calenderExtender controls it is working fine.